# WSL Ubuntu 18.06 LTS - Deny Read & Execute but not Read?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, onedrive, acl

I'm trying to setup an `id_rsa` key in WSL Ubuntu 18.06 LTS and I want permissions of 600, so `u+r` only.  And I'm told that the Windows FS ACL's override those of Linux.

Of course my `.ssh` directory is stored on my OneDrive and I'd like to Allow Read, but Deny Write and Execute, but I can't because there's a checkbox in the ACLs called `Read & execute` and thus I can't Deny Execute and allow Read.

Comment: I don't know what OneDrive does but if any program modify files WSL side permissions will be removed also. Try to mount the drive with `metadata` options and correct fmask flag in `/etc/well.conf`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Can I do that for just the one directory?

Comment: I don't know if its possible or not. I will try to find any Linux-Fu if possible. In the previous comment, the file name is `/etc/wsl.conf`.